# Having or not having Brand Name of end of the title has any effect SEO Wise

Tags: seo, google, title

Assume that my website is examplewebdesign.com.

Having or not having Brand Name of end of the title has any effect SEO Wise?

Ex 01 : Why your website should be mobile friendly?

Ex 02 : Why your website should be mobile friendly? | Example Web Design

Is there difference between above titles SEO wise? Which title Google Loves

Answer (score 2):

Google add brand name automatically if your title is short, so in reality you should not add brand name in your title. Here is example of my website. It add my site name automatically, because my title length on that page is short.

[image]

If you just want to know weather brand name add any SEO value, then the simple answer is NO. Google use title name to score document page. For example *"why my business site should be mobile friendly?"* so in this query user not adding your brand name in search, hence it will not add any value, but if user type *"how to dual bot my windows howtogeek"*  then Google will score that document higher, hence [Google said here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en) brand your title. Here the name in URL also impact in position, but it's all about weather user type your brand name in query or not.