# Should the brand name appear in each tag title even if it repeats keywords or dilutes from the targeted keyword phrase?

Tags: seo, keywords, title, branding

I found in other [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/111209/93492) that the brand name repeated in every tag title doesn't add any value for SEO. But I'd like to include the brand name in tag title to give strength to the name of the company in a communication project. So, I was wondering if repeating in each tag title the brand name of the company could penalize my SEO. For example, I'm focusing on the keyword "Hotel in Australia" for my australian customer who owns the Hotel Sydney. Is it worth to use this structure:

"Hotel in Australia | Hotel Sydney"

Hotel Sydney will be repeated after the separator for each page and each keyword. My doubts are:

- Repeating twice the keyword in the SEO title could be an overstuffing?
- Does the tag title "Hotel in Australia | Hotel Sydney" loose its SEO force (considering that my keyword is "Hotel in Australia" and the brand name is "Hotel Sydney"), for example being less foundable by those who search not a Hotel specifically in Sydney, but just a hotel in Australia?

Comment: I think your first priority should be learning how to spell “Sydney” ;)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat D'oh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be cautious if the keyword you will use as a brand name consists general words, However using brand names will establish your brand for both user & search engines.

A good example is:

Best Tech Company in Australia | iGeekTech

in your case your title is bad since it repeats the word and also now search engine may give more importance to Sidney since title tag is one of the main place where we use keywords and also may give users a wrong impression since they won’t know whether it’s a name or a hotel in Sidney.

If I were in your shoes I would write something similar to “Hotel Sidney - A Luxury Hotel in Australia” then I can make it clear for Search Engines through on page SEO, Schema & Back links what is the brand name and what is the keyword. Also, the users when read this title they will know Hotel Sidney is the name.

Comment: Another problem with "Best tech company" is using the superlative.   People tend to identify words such as "best", "greatest", etc as marketing speak.   That may actually reduce click through rate.

Answer (score 3):

There is no hard and fast rule for this but there are few things you need to keep in mind while using your brand name in all of your site's pages title tag.

1. Google Doesn't like repetition of same words again and again.
2. Length of title tag has limited number of characters available so you it doesnt look good to add your brand name in all of your pages title.
3. It will discourage people to share your content specially competitors.

Comment: I"d add that you no longer need to use phrases exactly in the title to be able to rank.   The natural title for them would be "Hotel Sydney" and the only keyword in their phrase that needs to be added is "Australia".    A title like "Hotel Sydney in Australia" would be a much more natural way of writing it that doesn't repeat keywords.